# GLSL lowp: syntax error

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

Why is the following shader, not compiling on OpenGL (Desktop) - but on OpenGL ES 2.0 (iPhone) it runs well (and I use the same c/c++ code to load, compile & link the shader on both plattforms).
My FragmentShader:

```
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = colorVarying;
}
```

The Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;

varying vec4 colorVarying;

uniform float translate;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    gl_Position.y += sin(translate) / 2.0;

    colorVarying = color;
}
```

The compile Log looks like this:

```
Shader compile log:
ERROR: 0:9: 'lowp' : syntax error syntax error
ERROR: Parser found no code to compile in source strings.
Failed to compile fragment shaderProgram validate log:
Validation Failed: Program is not successfully linked.
Failed to validate program: 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You misplaced the vertex shader with the fragment one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up through GLSL 1.1, `lowp` isn't mentioned in the GLSL specs.
In GLSL 1.2 (which goes with OpenGL 2.1) `lowp` is reserved for the implementation.
In GLSL 1.3 (which goes with OpenGL `lowp` started to be allowed (but is meaningless).

As such, it appears that whatever you're using on your desktop only recognizes an older version of GLSL. The obvious fix is to just delete it, or for the desktop, add a macro like:

```
#ifdef DESKTOP
#define lowp
#endif
```

with `DESKTOP` replaced by some identifier that's defined in whatever environment you're using on your desktop, but not whatever environment you're using for the iPhone.

Edit: Getting this into the source code can be non-trivial in itself. One way is like this:

```
char const *shader = 

#ifdef DESKTOP
    "#define lowp\n"
#endif

"varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;\n"

/* ... */
;
```

This way, "lowp" gets defined to nothing in the shader if and only if DESKTOP has been set in the host environment.

Comment: actually, if you use newer features of the language, you have to specify as much in the code: #version 130. Otherwise (according to spec), the GL compiler is supposed to compile it as a 110 shader.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you put in #version 130, it will no longer compile on OpenGL/ES.  You'll have to wait for OpenGL/ES 3.0 and OpenGL 4.2 if you want to be able to write a shader that will work on either with a single "#version 300 ES" in the top of the shader

Comment: How do you get that identifier into the shader?  From what I can see, the only one defined in there is GL_ES, to get anything else in, you'd have to pass it into `glShaderSource` as another shader string.

Comment: @rich.e: You normally do the `#ifdef`/`endif` in the surrounding source code, but the `#define lowp` is actually a string that's concatenated to the front of the string defining the shader. See edited example.